VSCode Conditional Breakpoint (Python)
I can not get VSCode to stop on a simple conditional breakpoint for a python project.
Enviroment:
OS: Windows 10
Language: Python
Version: VSCode 1.87.2
Breakpoint I am trying to implement is based on chunk_count which is a integer based counter in my code:
if (chunk_count in (38, 39, 40) 

I also tried
if (chunk_count==39)

Setting a breakpoint manually at the right time in the loop and evaluating these expressions on the debugger terminal shows they evaluate to True so what am I doing wrong?


Have you tried just chunk_count in (38, 39, 40)

Legend - thank you @Ftagliacarne. Put it as an answer and I vote it.

When adding conditional breakpoints in VS code they should be expressions that evaluate to true or false. This simply means that the statement is what you would put after an if statement if it were in code. i.e.
# If this would be in code
if cond:
    breakpoint()
    pass

# This is what you should put in VS code
cond

In your case, the correct statement would be:
chunk_count in (38, 39, 40)

